# How can I on-DOMCharacterDataModified with clojurescript regent

Tags: clojurescript

I'm currently trying to do :on-DOMCharacterDataModified so that I can see when a [:div] with {:contentEditable true} is edited.

How can I do this or should I be approaching this problem differently?  I'm using this type of text input field so that I can highlight parts of the text input with different colors.

Answer (score 0):

:on-input worked and then using (-> e .-target .-innerHTML) or (-> e .-target .-innerText) will get the new value.